# Aggregate group by results into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm trying to perform a sql query on multiple tables and count and average certain values while grouping by the project id. This is my sql query:

```
select p.id,
       count(e.id) as count, 
       avg(opened) as opened,
       avg(read_email) as clicked,
       avg(started_video) as started_watching,
       sum(views) as views
from   projects p
       inner join guests g
       on g.project_id = p.id
       inner join videos v
       on v.guest_id = g.id
       inner join emails e
       on e.video_id=v.id
group by p.id;
```

This is the table that is returned:

```
id count opened clicked started_watching views
-- ----- ------ ------- ---------------- -----
 2     1 1.0000  1.0000           1.0000     1
 3     3 0.3333  0.3333           0.3333     2
```

I want to further aggregate on these results and ideally return just one row. For instance I want to be able to count(opened) / count as avgOpened, count(clicked) / count as avgClicked, count(started_watching) / count as avgWatched, count(views) as totalViews, etc...

I was wondering whether there is an elegant way to do this in sql or whether this processing should be done programmatically. Also wondering whether it would be efficient to do this in sql or not.

Comment: So by one row, remove the *id* grouping?

Comment: I think you what to do a sum instead of count, isn't? Please show us your expected result.

Comment: You have tagged PostgreSQL, MySQL and Oracle - they are three different RDBMSes. Which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this the subquery for a join so this way you can use the results of this query to calculate and group further:

```
SELECT p.ID, count(opened)/x.opened
FROM projects p 
JOIN ( SELECT p.id, count(e.id) as count, avg(opened) as opened,
              avg(read_email) as clicked, avg(started_video) as started_watching,
              sum(views) as views
        FROM projects p  
        INNER JOIN guests g
          ON g.project_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN videos v  
          ON v.guest_id = g.id
        INNER JOIN emails e
          ON e.video_id=v.id
        GROUP BY p.id
     ) x
GROUP BY p.id ;
```